# Link Functions Outside Image Boundary

Tags: html, css

So if I add a link to an image, the link area goes the entire width of the page, which is beyond the size of the image. Here's my entire CSS code:

```
img {
display: block;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

However, I've deduced this happens due to this single line:

```
display: block;
```

I want my images to be centered and mobile-friendly, so I don't think I can change this coding, but is there something I can do to the a element that'll prevent the link area from extending outside my images?

Here's a test page: [Link](http://www.gloryhood.com/articles/zzzztest.html)

Comment: Bump. No answers? I added a test page if that helps.
http://www.gloryhood.com/articles/zzzztest.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this coding, while maintaining mobile-friendliness.

One way to do this would be to create an overlaying `<div>` that has it's text centered. Then set the `max-width` of the image to `100%`. And you're done.

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <a href="http://www.gloryhood.com/images/free-will-1.png">
    <img src="http://www.gloryhood.com/images/free-will-1.png" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code ([see example](http://codepen.io/kaarel/pen/JdjwVY)), your image is centered and mobile friendly:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%
}
```

When your page gets more complicated than that, it helps to wrap images (or even whole content block) within container *div*-s to help with the positioning part.